# Sum up total data on the same date and group them by date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a transaction table below

```
id | amount | created_at
1  |  300   | 2021-01-01
2  |  400   | 2021-01-01
3  |  150   | 2021-01-02
4  |  600   | 2021-01-03
```

How do I total up all the amounts with the same date and display them group by created_at?

I've tried this so far but it seems wrong

```
$query->selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount, created_at')
            ->groupBy('created_at')
            ->get()
            ->map(function($item){
                return [
                    'date' => date('d M', strtotime($item->created_at)),
                    'total' => $item->amount
                ];
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems wrong"? What makes you think that? Do you get any error message or wrong output?

Comment: @shaedrich it gives like duplicate results

Comment: You can omit the `map()` and change the query to `sum(amount) as total, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d %M')`

Comment: Besides that, your query looks fine. Is the `created_at` column really just a date or is it datetime?

Answer (score 2):

If the `created_at` field is date format, your code won't have the problem you described in the comment ([duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968081/sum-up-total-data-on-the-same-date-and-group-them-by-date#comment120134448_67968081)).
I'm pretty sure that the column is not really date format but datetime.

You can use `DATE(created_at)` to actually convert it to date format :

```
$query->selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount, DATE(created_at) as date')
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'date'  => date('d M', strtotime($item->date)),
            'total' => $item->amount,
        ];
    });
```

Comment: yeah, my bad. its a datetime. no wonder it duplicates. thanks